# What's time complexity of this algorithm for Wildcard Matching?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, recursion, big-o

> **Wildcard Matching**
>  Implement wildcard pattern matching with support for '**?**' and '*****'.
>
> - '?' Matches any single character.
> - '*' Matches any sequence of characters (including the empty    sequence).
>
> The matching should cover the entire input string (not partial).
>
> **The function prototype should be:**
>  bool isMatch(const char *s, const char *p)
>
> **Some examples:**
>
> - isMatch("aa","a") → false
> - isMatch("aa","aa") → true
> - isMatch("aaa","aa") → false
> - isMatch("aa", "*") → true
> - isMatch("aa", "a*") → true
> - isMatch("ab", "?*") → true
> - isMatch("aab", "c*a*b") → false
>
> ---

**Question:**

- What's time complexity?
- What's space complexity?

**Personally, I think**

- Time complexity highly dependents on the "input", can not write it
  out like T = O(?).
- Space complexity = O(min(sLen, pLen)), because the max recursion
  depth = O(min(sLen, pLen)).

**Have tried:**
Write out Time complexity Expression, then draw recursion tree:

```
TC Expression => T(n) = T(n - 1) + O(1),            when pChar == '?' or pChar == sChar,
                      = T(n - 1) + T(n - 1) + O(1), when pChar == '*'.
```

I tried to draw recursion tree, but can not figure out how to draw it based on this kind of Time Complexity Expression.

**Additional question:**
Accurately, I hope to know how to calculate the time complexity **for this kind of recursion**, which has multi-unforeseen-branch based on input.

**Note:**

- I know both iterative-solution and recursive-solution, but can not
  figure out how to calculate time complexity for the
  recursive-solution.
- And this is not homework, this question is from "leetcode.com", I
  just hope to know the method how to calculate time complexity for
  this special kind of recursion.

---

**Code:** Java, **Solution:** Recursion.

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean isMatch(String s, String p) {
        // Input checking.
        if (s == null || p == null) return false;

        int sLen = s.length();
        int pLen = p.length();

        return helper(s, 0, sLen, p, 0, pLen);
    }

    private boolean helper(String s, int sIndex, int sLen,
                           String p, int pIndex, int pLen) {
        // Base case.
        if (sIndex >= sLen && pIndex >= pLen) return true;
        else if (sIndex >= sLen) {
            // Check whether the remaining part of p all "*".
            while (pIndex < pLen) {
                if (p.charAt(pIndex) != '*') return false;
                pIndex ++;
            }
            return true;

        } else if (pIndex >= pLen) {
            return false;
        }

        char sc = s.charAt(sIndex);
        char pc = p.charAt(pIndex);

        if (pc == '?' || pc == sc) {
            return helper(s, sIndex + 1, sLen, p, pIndex + 1, pLen);

        } else if (pc == '*') {
            return helper(s, sIndex, sLen, p, pIndex + 1, pLen) ||
                   helper(s, sIndex + 1, sLen, p, pIndex, pLen);

        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that your question is alright.  I am going to edit out a bit of the noise about downvotes though; they happen and they don't necessarily warrant explanation (especially if the person doesn't want to give you one).

Comment: As a note - if you use recursion with memoization (essentially, top-down DP), this should be very fast because there are so many overlapping subproblems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to get an upper bound (i.e., big-O) on the worst case running time, you need to assume the very worst. The correct recurrence for an upper bound on the asymptotic running time of matching a string of length `s` with a pattern of length `p` is as follows.

```
T(s, p) | s == 0 || p == 0 = 1
        | s >  0 && p >  0 = 1 + max(T(s, p - 1) + T(s - 1, p),  // *
                                     T(s - 1, p - 1))            // ? or literal
```

Solving two-variable recurrences like this can be tricky. In this particular case, one can show fairly easily by induction that `T` is non-decreasing in both arguments, and so we can simplify the max.

```
T(s, p) | s == 0 || p == 0 = 1
        | s >  0 && p >  0 = 1 + T(s, p - 1) + T(s - 1, p)
```

Now one, with experience, can recognize the strong resemblance to a recurrence for [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) and make the (admittedly slightly magical) substitutions `s = n - k` and `p = k` and `T(s, p) = 2 U(n, k) - 1`.

```
2 U(n, k) - 1 | n == k || k == 0 = 1
              | n >  k && k >  0 = 1 + 2 U(n - 1, k - 1) - 1 + 2 U(n - 1, k) - 1

U(n, k) | n == k || k == 0 = 1
        | n >  k && k >  0 = U(n - 1, k - 1) + U(n - 1, k)
```

We conclude that `T(s, p) = 2 U(s + p, p) - 1 = 2 ((s + p) choose p) - 1 = O(2^(s + p)/sqrt(s + p))` by Stirling's approximation (that's the best big-O bound possible in the single quantity `s + p`, but it's confusing if I write big-Theta).

So far we have proved only that `T(s, p)` is an upper bound. Since `*` was the more troublesome case, an idea for the worst case presents itself: make the pattern all `*`s. We have to be a little bit careful, because if the match succeeds, then there's some short-circuiting possible. However, it takes very little to prevent a match: consider the string `0000000000` and the pattern `**********1` (adjust the number of `0`s and `*` as desired). This example shows that the quoted bound is tight to within a polynomial factor (negligible, since the running time already is exponential).

---

For the purpose of getting just an upper bound, it's not necessary to work out these recurrences nearly so precisely. For example, I might guess that `T(s, p) <= 3^(s + p)` and proceed to verify that claim by induction.

```
T(s, p) | s = 0 || p = 0  = 1 <= 3^(s + p)                 // base case
        | s > 0 || p > 0  = 1 + T(s, p - 1) + T(s - 1, p)  // induction
                         <= 3^(s + p - 1) + 3^(s + p - 1) + 3^(s + p - 1)
                          = 3^(s + p)
```

Now, `3^(s + p)` is a valid upper bound, though in light of the rest of this answer it's not tight. One now can look for waste in the bounds; `1 <= 3^(s + p - 1)`, for example, is a gross overestimate, and with some tricks, we can get the exponential base `2`.

The more important order of business, however, is to get an exponential lower bound. From drawing the recursion tree for the bad example above, I might conjecture that `T(s, p) >= 2^min(s, p)`. This can be verified by induction.

```
T(s, p) | s = 0 || p = 0  = 1 >= 2^min(s, p) = 2^0 = 1             // base case
        | s > 0 && p > 0  = 1 +     T(s, p - 1) +     T(s - 1, p)  // induction
                         >=     2^min(s, p - 1) + 2^min(s - 1, p)
                         >= 2^(min(s, p) - 1) + 2^(min(s, p) - 1)
                          = 2^min(s, p)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DavidEisenstat, I need some time to think about your answer deeply, the "substitution" to calculate time complexity is really skillful, it is a little hard to me.

Comment: @Zhaonan Yeah, I'm somewhat frustrated with that part of the answer. Like doing integrals in calculus, it's just one of those skills that takes time to cultivate. I worked on it because I find combinatorics beautiful, but it had surprisingly few uses in my professional life as a PhD student doing algorithms.

Comment: @Zhaonan Let me edit in what I would do if I didn't or couldn't recognize a well-known recurrence.

Comment: Thank you so much, you are very professional! I really happy to get the answer from you :)